# Sending the text file content using EventSource

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send the content of a text file (on the server) using EventSource. Here's the content of the file (`data.txt`):

```
2
0.42 1.30 -0.77 1.18 -0.03 1.56 0.42 0.11 -0.03 -1.95
0.40 -0.69 0.24 -0.26 0.63 0.68 0.20 -1.06 1.94 0.63
```

The reason I use EventSource is because this file will always be updated. Here's the server-side PHP code (`getData.php`):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$fid = fopen("data.txt", "r");
$N = fgets($fid);

for ($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) {
    $line = fgets($fid);
    $data[$i] = explode(" ", $line);
}
fclose($fid);

echo "data: {$N}\n";
for ($i=0; $i<1; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<9; $j++) {
        echo "data: {$data[$i][$j]}\n";
    }
}
echo "data: {$data[0][9]}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Here is the HTML code for the client:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var dataStr;

if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source=new EventSource("getData.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        dataStr = event.data;
    };
}
else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events.");
}

function changeVal() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = dataStr;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="result">This is a test.</p>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="changeVal()">Elements</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the HTML file and click the button, the displayed items are only:

```
0.42 1.30 -0.77 1.18 -0.03 1.56 0.42 0.11 -0.03 -1.95
```

and not

```
2 0.42 1.30 -0.77 1.18 -0.03 1.56 0.42 0.11 -0.03 -1.95
```

as I expected.

I tried a shorter data for the EventSource and modified the PHP code as follows:

```
...
echo "data: {$N}\n";
echo "data: {$data[0][9]}\n\n";
...
```

The button click displays only `-1.95`, and not `2 -1.95`.

Is there something wrong in my PHP code? Can I actually mix the string and array type and send them to the client using EventSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code.

It gives output as

```
 2 0.42 1.30 -0.77 1.18 -0.03 1.56 0.42 0.11 -0.03 -1.95 0.40 -0.69 0.24 
 -0.26 0.63 0.68 0.20 -1.06 1.94 0.63
```

Hope it helps

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$fid = fopen("data.txt", "r");

while(!feof($fid))
{
  $line =  fgets($fid);
  $data[] = explode(" ", $line);
}

fclose($fid);

foreach($data as $dat){
    foreach($dat as $d){
        echo "data: ". trim($d,$charlist = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ) ."\n";
    }
}

echo "\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works. Also found out that if I use `echo "data: ". trim($N) ."\n"` and `echo "data: ". trim($data[0][9]) ."\n\n"`, my code works. So the data for the EventSource must not contain whitespace, and `explode()` in PHP doesn't strip the whitespace. Am I right?

Comment: the problem was because of some special newline characters that where coming from the text file, and also the for loop for reading file was not working correct.